# Unity reflections going white with camera movement

Tags: unity, rendering, camera, reflection-rendering

Please refer to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7rR-DHjvu3A) to understand the issue I am facing.

With camera movement, there is a strong white reflection that appears over the complete model. What settings do I need to change to fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a specular problem. Assuming you're using the Unity 5 [Standard Shader](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/shader-StandardShader.html), try turning down the `Metallic` and `Smoothness` sliders, or the Specular's `Smoothness` slider if you're using the Specular workflow.

If you're using the **Metallic** workflow, and you supplied a texture to the `Metallic` map, keep in mind that:

> The Metallic levels for the material are controlled by the values in the **Red** channel of the texture, and the Smoothness levels for the material are controlled by the **Alpha** channel of the texture. (This means the **Green and Blue channels are ignored**).

(From [Unity's Metallic Parameter Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StandardShaderMaterialParameterMetallic.html))

Although, if you lower these sliders all the way, the smoothness won't have any effect.

If you still have the problem, you may want to look into the `Lighting` tab or see if there's any `Reflection Probes` that haven't been set up properly, but from the video it looks to be a specular issue.